# google visualization api not correctly formatted json

Tags: json, google-visualization

Hej guys!

I have a JSON file which i want to extract data from to visulaize data in a google bar chart. Google chart have a specific JSON format, but the data in the my file is of different JSON format. 
My question is that is it possible to convert my JSON file to the format, so that it manipulates google visualization api's format?

Googles format:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

The JSON-file format:

```
{
    "table.kot.educations": [
                            {"education":"Math","count":"8"},
                            {"education":"english","count":"15"},
                            {"education":"Management","count":"27"},
                            {"education":"Science","count":"14"},
                            {"education":"Social studies","count":"15"},
                            {"education":"Physics","count":"59"},
                            {"education":"Chemestry","count":"7"}
                            ],
    "table.user.educations":[
                            {"education":"Test i afdelingen med et meget meget meget meget langt navn","count":"2"},
                            {"education":"Test i IT-afdelingen","count":"3"},
                            {"education":"Test i PR-afdelingen","count":"2"}
                            ],
    "table.user.education.answer":[
                            {"education":"Math","answer":"N","count":"2"},
                            {"education":"Science","answer":"Y","count":"1"},
                            {"education":"Chemistry","answer":"N","count":"1"},
                            {"education":"Physics","answer":"Y","count":"1"}
                                  ]
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Both JSON files seem completly valid to me.
A JSON parser should ignore the indenting, as it's only used for better readability.

For instance, when creating a JSON string in PHP with *json_encode*, you can provide the additional argument "JSON_PRETTY_PRINT", but it shouldn't change the data itself - only make it easier for humans to read it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

If you want to convert it anyway, usually parsing the file to another data format (like YAML - which does rely on indentation btw) and convert it back, you'd may end up with the same indentations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew that both JSON formats are valid. I think that Graphs created with google visualization api only uses the JSON format mentioned above (Googles format). I want to convert my files JSON format to the one googles visualization api uses. Is there any easy way to convert from one JSON format to another?